# Unable to reference properties from imported file

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to refactor some code in my Angular 2/TypeScript project, but am having a little trouble.

Here is a simplified version of some code that I have, which works:

**example.component.ts:**

```
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {
    testString1: string;
    testString2: string;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.testString1 = 'first test string value';
        this.testString2 = 'second test string value';  
    }
}
```

While this example is clean, I have many more properties to define in my project. To reduce clutter, I want to define certain variables in a separate file and import them, so I did something like this:

**variables.ts:**

```
export class Variables {
    testString1: string;
    testString2: string;
}
```

**example.component.ts:**

```
import { Variables }  from './variables';

export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {    

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.testString1 = 'first test string value';
        this.testString2 = 'second test string value';
    }
}
```

The imported file was found, according to Visual Studios, but I get the following errors:

> Build:Property 'testString1' does not exist on type 'ExampleComponent'.
>
> Build:Property 'testString2' does not exist on type 'ExampleComponent'.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need testString1 and testString2 in your class when you using 'this':

```
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {    
    public testString1:string;
    public testString2:string;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.testString1 = 'first test string value';
        this.testString2 = 'second test string value';
    }
}
```

if you want the values from Variables class you have 2 ways:

1)

```
export class Variables {
    public static testString1: string;
    public static testString2: string;
}
```

and:

```
import { Variables }  from './variables';

export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {    

    ngOnInit(): void {
        Variables.testString1 = 'first test string value';
        Variables.testString2 = 'second test string value';
    }
}
```

2) Keep Variables as is now and do this:

```
 export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {    
        public variables:Variables = new Variables();

        ngOnInit(): void {

            this.variables.testString1 = 'first test string value';
            this.variables.testString2 = 'second test string value';
        }
    }
```

Good luck!

Comment: If I choose option 2, how does that effect displaying those values in the view? Do I need to make any changes there?

Comment: in the view of ExampleComponent you will be able to displaying those values, for example:

<div>{{variables.testString1}}</div>
<div>{{variables.testString2}}</div>